# missing required architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode7, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I have an old project, that I recompiled for an uodate, and it is now showing this error message:

```
 …. missing required architecture x86_64 in file myLibrary.a ….
```

I have tried various tricks that I could find on the net after searching on `missing required architecture x86_64 in file`, but with no success. Anyone knows how to properly handle the issue?

I am using Xcode Version 7.0.1.

Running:

```
lipo -info myLibrary.a
```

shows:

```
Architectures in the fat file: myLibrary.a are: armv7 arm64
```

I have been able to add armv7s but not x86_64.

Comment: are you included the standard architecture including 64-bit) (armv7, armv7s, arm64)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to build a universal library and it does not have all the architectures in it `armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64`. Compiler is complaining when you build with 64 bit architecture.

To fix this - Add the following to your architecture settings of static library project:

[image]

This needs manual addition of architectures something like this:

[image]

**Build the library with these architecture both on device & simulator, create fat library using `lipo -create -output "myLibrary.a" ./Simulator/myLibrary.a ./Device/myLibrary.a`** and use it.

Comment: Thanks. It works at least up to a certain point.
Running:
lipo -info myLibrary.a
now shows: 
Architectures in the fat file: myLibrary.a are: i386 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64 
But I now get this warning:
ld: warning: object file (myLibrary.a(myLibrary.o)) was built for newer iOS version (7.0) than being linked (6.0).
It makes sense, but even if I change the iOS Deployment Target from 6.0 to 7.0 it stays there. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like your minimum iOS version the library was built on is greater than the iOS version being used in your consumer app. While building your library (both on device & simulator), set  **Minimum Deployment Target** to **6.0**.

Comment: The library was built with iOS Deployment Target set to 7.0. I do not see any Minimum Deployment Target.

Comment: Yeah its **Deployment Target** only. It should be **6.0** and not **7.0** as in your consumer app  **Deployment Target** is set to **6.0**.

Comment: OK, I did it and the warning disappeared. Now I have these errors:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libMyLibrary.a(MyLibrary.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libMyLibrary.a(MyLibrary.o)

Comment: You need to ensure that all the classes used in your library & consumer application are built with the architectures I mentioned above. That is what is missing here.

Comment: I see, but _OBJC_CLASS_$_CIContext and _OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter are not classes of mine. So there is not much I can do if they are not compiled adequately by the builder (Apple I guess?). Or I maybe missing some point.

Comment: You must link with `CoreImage.framemwork` in your consumer application under your target's `Build Phases --> Link Binary With Libraries`

Comment: It seems like it is working, I still a few other details to check. Anyway the strange part is that I did not include this framework before for it to work.

Comment: Glad it helped... Cheers :)!