# Xcode - symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, xcode6

[image: after updating PODs]

Encountering this issue, after updating my Xcode pods.

Comment: Take a look at my response in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491858/missing-required-architecture-x86-64/33492109#33492109). Try to align your case according to this. Read the discussion comments as well; may help!

Answer (score 0):

```
So here's a little workaround. The problem is because the XCode project is unable to link to the libjpeg.a library. So thats why you get the above errors when you compile the project. 

Follow these steps : 

1. Go to : [[http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/files/1.4.0/]] and download the  libjpeg-turbo-1.4.0.dmg (3.8 MB) file.
2. Install the package. Once its done you will find the installed files under this path : */opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib*
3. Open up your terminal and type the following command : *lipo -info /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib/libjpeg.a*
4. If the terminal shows the following the output after running the command then it means, you can use the library for your iOS project(armv7/armv7s) 
   * Architectures in the fat file: /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib/libturbojpeg.a are: i386 x86_64 armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64* 
5. Use finder to navigate to : /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib and copy libjpeg.a and place it in your project folder.
6. Head over to your XCode project -> Click on Project Name -> Targets -> General -> Linked frameworks and libraries -> Click on the add button placed at the bottom -> include the libjpeg.a file
7. Compile the project. It shouldn't show any more linker errors.
```

However libjpeg errors fixed, still encountering this "architecture x86_64"